# Already mined block hash showing zeros at the end when I hash it in online sha256 two times

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, sha256

Hi I tried hashing a already mined block with this block header 04E0FF37f09be87b288284c8e93a04fff7b4ac9b72178c2e6b4e0a00000000000000000035788eca05bccfaede03db9cb6276e9f7c125687b9321939755f03d73f15bd25C4F2EE60CE9813175230D962 [of this block](https://blockchain.info/block-height/691000) and I hashed it two times but the output zero are at end of the hash. b11f24d772b9fee7132b62e0bd17fefa76d29848e6930c000000000000000000

How does it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re falling afoul of [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). To promote equality, Satoshi sought to use Big Endian representation for hashes in Bitcoin, which have the byte order the opposite of what you are producing.

Comment: Should we little endian the output hash?